# installing extensions for magento on cpanel

Tags: upload, cpanel, zip

i'm new on magento and i need to install extensions but i don't know how..
i tried to install an extension from the dashboard through the component manager but the readiness check gave an error on cron job and i couldn't solve the problem so i tried to download the extension as a zip file and extracted it here comes the question:
1-what files should i upload to cpanel from the extracted files?
2-In which folder in cpanel i must upload it?
3-what should i do after uploading it? I mean how will it work?

noting that i don't have the password of the root username but the manager of the host has invited me so that when i log in to cpanel this appears[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can install by cpanel as well as magento connect manager just login your credentials and install it

as i have done the same thing i just installed a extension for blog you can check here of my site its installed.
https://flowerportal.in